# How much money would I need to feel secure in my job?

Tags: financial-independence

I have my first good paying "career" position (I'm 27), but I've heard stories about around 10 years ago when they laid of 60% of the company. I'm worried that this could happen again because I believe another recession may happen sometime in the next few years.

My spending philosophy is to enjoy your money, but don't waste it every time you get a raise. Currently, here is my income/expenses:

Income/assets:

- $4,150/month from salary (after tax)
- $6,000 in stocks
- $4,000 in savings

Expenses (monthly):

- Car payment: $380 (but I've started to pay $500)
- Car insurance: $70
- Utilities & rent: $730
- Cell phone: $65
- Food: $600
- Credit card debt: $800 total, but I pay anywhere from $70 to $200 a month on it.
- Other (spending, subscriptions, etc): $500-$700
- Saving/Investing: The rest of the money. I break savings down into emergency vs vacation fund, but investments I view as a permanent savings account that I never touch.

I know my title question is really personal, but I'm really just trying to find an amount so that I don't panic if I was laid off and how I would get to that amount as quickly as possible. I'd like to upgrade my apartment because i have been living in the same place ever since I was only making $10/hour (5 years ago) and the walls are starting to close in on me. It's a small one bedroom.

Comment: Do you have any retirement savings?

Comment: Are the stocks in a retirement or other tax-deferred account?

Comment: @DStanley No. I really need to do something for retirement. My problem though is that I hate the thought of retirement. I don't want to work, then retire. Eventually I want to start a business so I want to accrue as much accessible money as I can.

Comment: Perhaps you should change your spending philosophy about enjoying  your money (spending it freely), pay down all debt and shift your mindset into saving more so that if there is indeed a recession and you are laid off, you'll be able to sustain yourself while you look for a new job?

Comment: @Jared that's fine - I was more wondering if you could tap into that without any significant tax consequences.

Comment: @DStanley The one good thing about my investments is that a good port of them are long term so I should only be taxed capital gains if I take them out.

Comment: $1300/month of "excess cash" while still carrying CC debt and paying it off **SLOWLY** is... puzzling.  Really puzzling.  Do you think that it builds your credit score?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: How much would it cost to buy the place your renting (or the place you want to rent in the near future)?

Comment: Why aren't you debt free with such an income?

Comment: I don't understand why you both have a credit card debt and savings. you pay interest on that debt. It's not like you would have less money if you paid it off with your savings. In case of emergency you could use that same credit card again

Comment: the very simple answer is "pay-off or sell the car, and pay-off the card".  debt ***is what makes people feel insecure***.  if you happen to lose your job, so what? you're young and smart, you'll get a new job.  but debt is fear.  the literal answer to your question is ***eliminate debt***.  income is nothing.

Comment: does the 600 in food include other entertainment expenses? Most people shold be able to get by on 300/month for food.

Comment: @IvoBeckers Imagine this situation: You pay off debts with savings you have. You loose your job and have no means to support yourself, bank will not give you credit to survive time between jobs because without work you are not really a reliable client.
If you had savings, you could at least survive until you get a new job.

Comment: You haven't tagged your location, but in the US "retirement savings" could be more aptly named "old age savings". You are generally not required to actually retire to access them, just to be over a certain age. And there are several schemes (401(k), IRA) that are either tax advantaged or come with employer matching (FREE MONEY), so there's a strong incentive to use them. (The downside is that it can be difficult to get money out before you reach old age...but did I mention FREE MONEY?)

Comment: "There are two ways to get enough. One is to accumulate more and more. The other is to desire less." If you want a case in point, look at the glut of articles about people who make 400k a year and still feel financially insecure. Or, to be more in the spirit of the season, think of Scrooge. Money will not bring you peace of mind, no matter how much of it you have. Better to learn not to fear a lack of money than to save "enough."

Comment: This, by the way, is probably imprudent (but not necessarily bad) advice for someone living paycheck to paycheck. You clearly aren't, or at least needn't be, so it's probably both prudent and good to think more about how to want less (materially) than how to have more.

Answer (score 34):

By my calculations you have about $2,800 in expenses and $10,000 in "savings" (including your stock). That's a decent (3.5 month) emergency fund that could be used in event of a layoff, and you could pare down some expenses to make it last longer. Plus, you could always find temporary work, even if it meant making half of what you do now.

So I wouldn't panic just yet. Certainly you could save a little more while you're working, but you're in a good position to weather most storms.

I would also consider paying off the car quickly. That would eliminate about $400 of your monthly expenses, making your emergency fund last even longer, or make a new apartment more affordable.

Bottom line - don't panic. A crash with the scope and magnitude of 2008 (meaning that you actually lost your *job*, not just some value in your investments) was hopefully a once-in-a-lifetime event, and even if something similar does happen again, there's nothing you can do about it but be prepared, which you are. You'll be better off than most people that have *no* savings and struggle to manage after getting laid off.

Comment: Thanks. That makes me feel a lot better.

Comment: I wouldn't consider stocks as part of the emergency fund. Depending on their value and the market, they can only be sold with losses.

Comment: @glglgl Well, I wouldn't have an emergency fund in stocks either, but would you rather go without electricity or sell some stock?

Comment: 2008 was hopefully a once-in-a-lifetime event? At 27, OP should have lived through the dotcom bust as well..

Comment: and by the time OP is 55, they could live through a S&L crisis, a commodities crisis, a computer-triggered black swan like October 1985 or whatever year that was, three war recessions, an Elder Boom (baby boom in reverse, what if his parents exhaust all their assets due to elder health issues), etc etc

Comment: @Stanley That's a good point, but of those two options, I'd prefer the third one: to avoid this decision by having enough liquid funds. Of course, that's a question of probabiity, i. e. if it is very unikely that I need this money, I'd rather have it work for me. But for now, the goal should be to increase the liquid savings up to a certain amound and only then to continue investing.

Comment: It's not a matter of if 2008 will happen again, but when, considering that there is no evidence anyone has learned anything.

Comment: @Mars - I'm talking about the _magnitude_ of 2008. Certainly there will be recessions but 2008 had a wider reach than even the dot-com bust. I'm skeptical that anything of that _magnitude_ will happen again for quite some time. But that's my opinion.

Comment: @Mars Some people reckon that recessions happen every 10-11 years. Which means there should be another one right about ***now***.

Answer (score 20):

I don't know how expensive it is to live where you live, but IMO your expenses are too high by far.

Your expenses should reduce to:

- Car insurance: $70 → probably ok
- Utilities & rent: $730 → probably ok
- Cell phone: $65 → probably ok, but maybe you find a cheaper plan
- Food: $600 → seems very much to me. You should be able to halve this value.
- Other (spending, subscriptions, etc): $500-$700 → This as well should be able to be reduced, let's say $400.

(You'll see that I deliberately omitted the following points: Car payment, Credit card debt and Saving/Investing. That's because these are no permanent points, but rather ones which should be eliminated ASAP. We'll see later how.)

So far, we are at $1565 (instead of $1965-$2165 before). That's still quite a lot.

From your $4165, you now have left $2600 (instead of $2000-$2200 before).

From this money, you can eliminate your CC debt immediately, and probably a significant part of your car loan. In some months (depending on how much of the principal is left), you are rid of it.

Once you are at this point, the whole $2000 to $2600 is free to be saved.

If you are really afraid of being unemployed, you should have an emergency fund of about 3 to 12 times your monthly expenses (depending on what makes you feel the safest), so let's say about $5000 to $18000. Don't consider the stocks you have as emergency cash, however, because you might to be able to sell them under value, what would be a loss after all.

But anyway, you should have reached your goal in about 3 to 9 months. The money you earn then can all be invested long-term, or you increase your cushion even more.

---

Additional thoughts about your wish to upgrade your apartment:

If I was in your shoes, I'd postpone this step until after your CC debt and your car loan are paid off fully and you have enough money left to at least cover the costs of moving.

Otherwise, you might end up in even more debt.

Comment: Is the 12 months worth of emergency fund your personal opinion, or are you drawing from a source for it?  I ask because I've always heard 3-6 months is satisfactory.

Comment: @bvoyelr In the end, that's up to each individual. The more you have, the safer you can feel. I had the feeling that the OP feels rather unsafe, so a bit more of a cushion might be favourable.

Comment: @bvoyelr especially if somebody is worried about layoff in a crisis 6-12 month seem to be more realistic.

Comment: $730 for rent is _definitely_ OK for someone making over $4000 a month. Don't scare the poor guy.. $730 is well beyond great, in fact: much less than a fourth of his paycheck after tax. Most people pay way more than that.

Comment: @only_pro I didn't say anything else. That's why I considered it as "probably ok". The other points of his budget were where I suggested changes.

Comment: @glglgl And I'm saying it's definitely OK. No need to induce any sort of doubt with the "probably".

Comment: @only_pro While I agree, lifestyle inflation is a thing, and it happens primarily through houses and cars.  The only way to prevent it is constant, unwavering commitment.  Which is to say, a little fear can be a good thing -- some financial decisions cannot be easily undone, so it's better *not to make them* than to find out after the fact that they were mistakes.  From first hand experience, a house payment that looks fine on paper is way less attractive when it's coming out of your bank account!

Comment: 12 months of salary sitting in a low interest is wasting capital. He would be paying a handsome and invisible fee for all that liquidity he is not using. I do agree to have savings at 3-4x your monthly *expenses* but 12x seems excessive. Stocks and bonds can also be emergency funds but they are less liquid and shouldn't be counted as 1$ = 1$ (more like half). The savings are for having liquidity enough to release the rest of your assets in case sh...

Comment: @StianYttervik It probably pays to spell out that OP will have several months' time to sell the stock if/when he needs the money. Taking into account that stocks may go down is reasonable but they're more than liquid enough. (Assuming here large enough companies and 3-4 months cash + rest in stock)

Comment: @StianYttervik "…shouldn't be counted as 1$ = 1$ (more like half)." That's exactly the point: in the case of emergency, I don't want to lose half of the money in question. YMMV. In the end, it can be seen as a kind of insurance: do I risk the opportunity cost of having the money "lying around", or do I risk the cost of halving my assets in the case of emergency? That deneds, among others, on the probability that such an event (unemployment of more than 6 months) occurs. As other answers already state, that depends on several curcumstances.

Comment: On the other hand, if we see CDs with a fixed, high enough rate and a time of 6, 9 or 12 months as a valid compromise between safety and profitability, we of course can choose to take them.
Or we do an appropriate mix of saving account, CDs, bonds and stocks/ETFs and draw the line between "emergency" and "for the future" wherever we need it.

Comment: @glglgl While double jeopardy is more likely than never, it still seems reasonable to assume (but of course not all in on) both a crash and an emergency at once. The fear of losing should be balanced against the permanent inefficiency. Most people err way too much on the side of caution.

Comment: Also, good, healthy food might not be affordable where OP lives.

Comment: Car insurance of $70/mo is probably vastly overpriced. Usually if you're paying monthly rather than every 6 months for car insurance, your monthly payment is between 50 and 75% of what your payment would be. I wouldn't be surprised if you could switch to paying for half a year at a time and drop the total from $840/yr to $500/yr or less.

Answer (score 17):

> How much money would I need to feel secure in my job?

As much money as is needed to tide you over until you find a new job.

It's no more complicated than that, really.

Of course, "until you find a new job" is the tricky part to figure out, which depends on:

1. where you live,
2. what your profession is,
3. what industry it is, and
4. how willing you are to move.

Comment: The rule of thumb I work to is that I need to have a reserve of sufficient capital to cover me for six months of unemployment. If I'm still unemployed after that, I'm probably in deeper trouble than I can save for. The furthest it's been tested has been four months.

Answer (score 8):

You asked the question pretty well, but frankly there is nothing you can do to feel secure in your job.  Keep increasing your skills and work hard and you will be employable.  The company might go under, but knowing how to earn is a key skill that keeps one "employed".  It is very likely, statistically speaking, that you will change jobs in the next 3 years.  You might want to read the book **Who Moved My Cheese**.  There is also a Zig Ziglar anecdote which talked about a grocery delivery boy that was always hustling.  Not only was he always employable, but he also deserved a raise.

Now to feel more financially independent, you really need to eschew consumer debt.  You make pretty good money and your expenses are not bad, but the car payment and CC is killing you.  Despite the ability to earn points and what not, it is time for you to cut up your credit card.  If you carry a balance, then you need to be done.  Perhaps after a year or so of no CC balance, you can then go back to earning points and stuff.

To me this is your budget:

```
Car payment: $380 
Car insurance: $70
Utilities & rent: $730
Cell phone: $65
Food: $600  <- Can this be cut?
Other (spending, subscriptions, etc): Cut to $400
Total:  $2245
```

This gives you a positive cash flow of 1905 for the month.  So pay off your CC in full.  Then cut it up.  Use the remaining 1100 towards your car payment.  You don't talk about a balance on your car loan, but in subsequent months you should be able to pay around $2300 per month on the car loan.  So in less than a year you could owe 23K less on your car, that will probably pay it off.

Having no car payment and no CC payment will give you a nice free cash flow.  Also if you do get laid off those are obligations you do not need to pay.  I would also avoid individual stocks in favor of mutual funds, but that is a bit of ways off.

Comment: Disagree with the advice to cut up your credit card. Better to keep your card but never carry a balance on it (i.e. pay it off in full every month). Many cards have rewards programs that will give you 1-4% cashback; or discounts on car rentals; or free travel insurance which is easily worth $200-$500 a year depending on your spending habits.

Comment: "There is also a Zig Ziglar antidote" I think the intended word was anecdote.

Comment: Don't cut up your credit card.. terrible advice. _Use_ your credit card as much as possible to reap the rewards points, and _always_ pay it off in full each month. This will both build credit and give you free money.

Comment: In the UK (dunno about elsewhere) you can set up a Direct Debit with your bank that automatically pays off the CC in full each month. I always do that with all my cards and never pay interest on them.

Answer (score 5):

Feeling secure is very subjective and it really depends on multiple factors, as said by RonJohn. Here is my take: you should have this amount of cash in your savings for different cases:

### Case 1:

- 3 months salary in cash saved up ($12,450 using your after tax monthly salary of $4150)
- No dependents
- No debt
- You are in an industry with lots of job openings
- Takes you less than 1 month to find a job

### Case 2:

- 3-6 months salary ($12,450-$24,900)
- You are in an industry which has some job openings
- It takes you at least 1-2 month to find a new job
- You have some debt

### Case 3:

- 6 month-1 year salary ($24,900-$49,800)
- You are in an industry which doesn't have that many job openings
- You have debt
- You have at least 1 dependent
- It takes you more than 3 months to find another job

I recommend also checking out Dave Ramsey's 7 baby steps which also includes establishing a $1000 emergency fund. https://www.daveramsey.com/dave-ramsey-7-baby-steps

Comment: I wonder if it is correct to calculate in multiples of after tax salary or if it would be better to calculate in multiples of monthly costs. Because, as long as you are living off your savings, you don't have to add to the savings. These considerations would about halve the needed savings value.

Comment: Seconding @glglgl.  All keeping that much cash on hand will do is make you miss out on the compound interest yielded by investments.  Remember, having cash makes us feel nice, but *it loses value every year due to inflation*, so we should only keep as much as we can reasonably expect to need on short notice.  The rest should be in a savings vehicle that at least keeps up with inflation  Keeping more cash is just short changing yourself (which is your prerogative if you feel your situation demands it!)

Answer (score 1):

Besides the excellent ideas in other questions, a couple observations:

Nowadays, 6 months' cushion may not be enough.  Fortunately, you are at the beginning of your career, so you have some flexibility.  One thing to consider is whether your job may become obsolete by the "Next Big Thing" -- so as others have suggested, consider learning new skills. I thought a couple times that my job was secure, but when a company announces a 15% job force reduction, you get nervous.  I know recent college graduates that were unable to find a job in their field for over a year.

First priority as others suggested is paying off car loan, reducing expenses, etc. but besides building up your savings, be sure to take advantage of deferred compensation plans such as 401(k) plans in the United States.   If your employer matches contributions up to a certain percent (3 to 6% match are common), that is like getting a 3 to 6% percent raise. If you start early in your career, you could have several million dollars at retirement.

Answer (score -2):

Several answers here are very good, but I don't feel that any are 100% adequate. I hope my answer adds value and isn't just noise. And full disclosure, I am a Dave Ramsey disciple so I'm just going to say what he would say.

You should have $6,500 - $13,000 for you to feel secure, which is 3-6 months of expenses if I've done my math correctly (excluding debt payments which I'll address presently). But before you do that, you need to pay off your debt. I want you to imagine that you have $8,000 in the bank, but you have a car payment and credit card debt, and then you get laid off. How does that feel? Now imagine you have $8,000, no car payment, no credit card debt, and you get laid off. How does that feel? It feels better doesn't it? It isn't difficult to figure out that the more debt you have, the quicker your emergency fund is going to be eaten away.

SpartaSixZero makes an excellent point that the exact amount of money to help you feel secure will vary depending on how stable and how in-demand your career is, and how many dependents you have, but your debt should not be a factor because you should pay that off asap. And the reason Dave Ramsey recommends 6 months and no more for an emergency fund is exactly the reasons glglgl and bvoyelr point out in their comments on SpartaSixZero's answer: you have too much money that isn't doing anything.

Dave Ramsey outlines 7 Baby Steps:

1. Baby Emergency Fund: save a $1,000 emergency fund, and nothing more. If anyone quibbles about this it's usually that they believe their emergency fund should be larger, but at this stage you should feel uncomfortable because you're in debt, and saving up a large emergency fund is going to keep you in debt longer. There are *very rarely* exceptions to this, and I do not think your situation is one.
2. Debt Snowball: list all of your debts smallest to largest, and throw every dime you can at the smallest debt until it's paid off, then move to the next largest, etc. Paying off debt this way builds up emotional momentum, which is much more valuable than paying off your debts from largest interest rate to smallest.
3. Emergency Fund: fill out your emergency fund to cover 3-6 months of expenses.
4. Retirement: save 15% of your salary for retirement. This 15% should not include any employer-match. If your employee matches 3% of your contributions, do not use that as an excuse to put only 12% of your paycheck away, you should instead put a full 15% away.
5. Children: save for your kids' college (if you don't have any children yet, don't save yet).
6. House: Pay off your house early (or begin saving for a down payment if you don't yet have a mortgage).
7. Enjoy: Be outrageously generous.

You're already past Baby Step 1 which is good, but you have debt so you need to tackle that before going any further. If you have less than $3,000 in debt, take the money from your savings and pay off all your debt today, cut up your credit cards, and vow to never go into debt again (with the unfortunate exception of a mortgage). If you have more than $3,000 in debt, and your stocks are not in retirement accounts, sell off all the stock necessary to pay off the debt. If you have more than $9,000 in debt, go down to a $1,000 emergency fund, throw everything you have saved at the debt, then continue with Baby Step 2.

At this point, some people complain about taking money out of an investment to pay off debt. And let me reiterate, do not take out money from a retirement account for any reason except to prevent a bankruptcy; the fees and taxes are just too much. But you absolutely should sell all other investments to pay off debt, and here's why. Almost no one would agree to go into debt to invest in something. It's a good way to lose everything you have. And those who would agree to do it aren't wise. But from a financial standpoint, that's exactly what you've done, you've borrowed money on a car to invest in some stocks.

So once you're debt free, your next step is to build up your emergency fund to at least $6,500, but maybe more if it will take you more than a month or two to find another job. But do not have more than $13,000 in your emergency fund.

Once you have a real emergency fund you can either do what Dave calls Baby Step 3b, which is to save for at most 2 years for a down payment for a house. No more than 2 years because you're probably under-saving for retirement to save for the down payment, and missing out on more than 2 years of retirement savings in your late 20s is just too much. After 3b, or instead of 3b, start saving 15% of your paycheck towards retirement. It sounds like you don't have children so I'm assuming you can skip Baby Step 5. And so on.

I get the feeling you don't have a whole lot of debt, so you can probably have your emergency fund fully-funded within a year, maybe sooner. And if you want to really throw gasoline on this fire, get a second job delivering pizzas or something, where you can make another $1,000/month. That will absolutely catapult you through this process.

And lest you're still concerned that you're missing out on investment returns at this age, if you invest just $623/month (which is 15% of your current paycheck, which you're going to get raises throughout your career so these are really low numbers in reality) at 10% (historically the stock market has done over 12%) from the age of 30 to 60, you will have just a hair under 1.3 million dollars. And if you follow Dave Ramsey's plan, you're going to build so much financial discipline and good habits that you're going to wind up with quite a lot more than that in reality.

Comment: I am the down voter. Because most of your answer has nothing to do with the OP’s situation. It comes off more as proselytizing the celebrity David’s position on finance, and could be copy/pasted to multiple questions here.

Comment: Fair enough. No regrets :)